# H2 DB DAY_OF_WEEK starting Monday

Tags: javascript, hibernate, date, h2, weekday

I need to get the day of the week of a date in H2 as a number. There is a function DAY_OF_WEEK(date) which returns Sunday as the first day of the week. 
However, I need Monday to be the first day of the week. Does someone know a function in H2 to accomplish this?

I need it for a "weekday" function in a custom hibernate dialect. The values returned shoud correspond to the values of the java DayOfWeek enum.

In MySQL I solved it like this:

```
registerFunction("weekday", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "WEEKDAY(?1)+1"));
```

Now I don't know how to accomplish this with H2. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found the H2 function `DAY_OF_WEEK (dateAndTime)`. Which is defined in the h2 function documentation and returns **1 as Sunday**.

```
DAY_OF_WEEK ( dateAndTime )
Returns the day of the week (1 means Sunday).
Example:
DAY_OF_WEEK(CREATED)
```

You can use `ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK ( dateAndTime )` if you want that **1 is mapped to Monday**. Which is defined as follows in the [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#iso_day_of_week).

```
ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK ( dateAndTime )
Returns the ISO day of the week (1 means Monday).
Example:
ISO_DAY_OF_WEEK(CREATED)
```

I hope that helps! :)